# Android - How to correctly write a JSONObject string

Tags: java, android, json, escaping

I'm trying to read/write a json file. But after the first write the json is escaped and reading it again doesn't work. I have the following json structure but with a lot more value :

```
{
  "events": {
    "XdQKixgtraz17eDHb6OW": {
      "department": "Côte-d'Or",
      "objectName": "Dijon",
      "uid": "PMhzfzWlm6vN2yL1kY2i"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how i build my json string :

```
JSONObject eventsJsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject eventsData = new JSONObject();

for(Event event: eventsList){
    String eventString = gson.toJson(event);
    eventsData.put(event.getUid(), eventString);
}

eventsJsonObject.put("events", eventsData);

writeFile(filename, eventsJsonObject.toString());
```

I end up with a string looking like this and i can't read it again .. :

```
{"events":{"XdQKixgtraz17eDHb6OW":"{\"department\":\"Côte-d'Or\",\"objectName\":\"Dijon\",\"uid\":\"PMhzfzWlm6vN2yL1kY2i\"}"}}
```

As you can see there is a quote before the third semi colon that shouldn't be there. How can i correctly build my json string ?

Thanks for your time.

Edit : The error came from where i build my json string to write in file so i have rewrite my question.

Comment: "I end up with a string looking like this" -- presumably, that is what you passed into `writeFile()` as `jsonString`. So, examine your code for creating `jsonString` and see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly, i simply use myJsonObject.toString() but i don't find a way to stringify it without escape characters.

Comment: Your code looks OK, so where did you see the string with escaped characters?

Comment: `where did you see the string with escaped characters?` when i try to read the file after i have write it. I write it as jsonObject.toString() so it's there that the json is escaped. If i use StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson it doesn't escape properly.

Comment: I have edited my question because there was no answer to give to the previous since the error wasn't coming from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static JSONObject readJSONFile (String path, Context context) {
String jsonStr = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open(path);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    jsonStr = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject((jsonStr ));
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Comment: There is no change. 
And i open the file from internal storage not assets.

Comment: I have edited my question because there was no answer to give to the previous since the error wasn't coming from that.